# programmatically have slider set label with in a uitableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Im trying to update my label when the slider moves though I may be missing something? perhaps the slider is not connected to the function?

```
let slider: UISlider = {
let s = UISlider()
s.minimumValue = 0
s.maximumValue = 1000
s.isContinuous = true
s.tintColor = UIColor.blue
s.value = 500
    s.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paybackSliderValueDidChange),for: .valueChanged)

    return s
}()

func paybackSliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider!)
{
    print("payback value: \(sender.value)")
    sliderLabel.text = "\(sender.value)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mark your `paybackSliderValueDidChange(sender:)` method as `@objc`. Otherwise, UIKit won't be able to access it in Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

just had to change "let slider: UISlider"  to "lazy var slider: UISlider"

and voila